# get data from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

am new to codeigniter and I want to develop todo app.now the problem is get data from database ,anyone findout and tell me what the error is,

get.php

```
       <html>
       <head>
    <title></title>
     </head>
    <body>

      <?php foreach($data as $row){?>
       <tr>

       <td><?php echo $row->task; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->date; ?></td>
       </tr>

     <?php }?> 
    </body>
     </html>
```

Add_task.php(model)

```
public function get_user()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data=$this->db->get('user');
    return $data->result();
}
```

Welcome.php(controller)

```
public function get_task($data)

    {
       $this->load->model('Add_task');
       $data=$this->Add_task->get_user();
       $this->load->view('get',$data);

    }
```

Am getting error like this

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/get.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Backtrace:

> File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.4\application\views\get.php Line: 8
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.4\application\controllers\Welcome.php
>   Line: 43 Function: view
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.4\application\controllers\Welcome.php
>   Line: 33 Function: get_task
>
> File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.4\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: ``$data`` is not defined in the get.php file.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your controller as:

```
public function get_task($data) { 
   $this->load->model('Add_task');
   $data["data"] =$this->Add_task->get_user();
   $this->load->view('get',$data); 
}
```

You need to pass associative array in load view `$data["data"]`

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter read your array by keys, so every variable you want pass to view you must put it as a key in your `$data` array like this:

```
public function get_task()
{
   $this->load->model('Add_task');
   $rows=$this->Add_task->get_user();
   $data['title'] = "page title";
   $data['rows'] = $rows;
   $this->load->view('get',$data);

}
```

and in your view, replace $data with $rows:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row){?>
   <tr>

   <td><?php echo $row->task; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row->date; ?></td>
   </tr>

 <?php }?>
```

Comment: @Ram.k if answer solved your issue, you accept it. when you have a reputation to vote up you can say thank you for who help you by vote up his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an associative array that contain your database result.

See you the [documentation page for views](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=data#creating-loops) at "Creating Loops" paragrapher

Welcome.php (controller)

```
public function get_task($data)
{
    $this->load->model('Add_task');
    $data['users'] = $this->Add_task->get_user();
    $this->load->view('get', $data);
}
```

And change the loop in your get.php (view) :

```
<?php foreach($users as $user) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user->task; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->status; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->date; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
$this->load->view('get',$data);
```

to

```
$this->load->view('get', ['data' => $data]);
```

and all be fine.

If you want to pass a variable into a view, you need to create correspond array index for it (with the same name but without the `$` sign). For example, if you want to have `$var1`, `$my_variable`, `$myCustomVariable`, and `$data` in the 'get' view, you need to pass it as:

```
$this->load->view('get', [
    'var1' => 'value of $var1',
    'my_variable' => 'value of $my_variable',
    'myCustomVariable' => 'value of $myCustomVariable',
    'data' => $data
]);
```